# File not found/read error if file accessed immediately after saving it

Tags: filesystems, nfs, network-share

I am running CentOS 7, working on a synchronously mounted network drive (NFS).

EDIT: more system info:
Server is running CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) with kernel 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 and NFS v4

```
% nfsstat -m 
/misc/workarea from 192.168.6.3:/workarea/
Flags: rw,relatime,vers=4,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.106,minorversion=0,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.6.1
```

The issue can be summarized as follows:

Say file system "feels slow", e.g. it takes longer than usual to see the `ls` results. If I then try to write to a file and then read it immediately after writing (in human timescale), I will get either `file not found` or `read/write error`.

Here is a couple of actual examples:

1. I am writing Perl code in one terminal tab and running it in another. I frequently save the file I am editing (`module.pm`, say) then immediately switch to another tab and run the script I am working on. If the file system "feels slow" and I am unlucky, I will get `could not find module.pm` error. Only if I re-run after several seconds the file will be found.
2. I am working on a Tcl script in one terminal tab. The script is used by a waveform viewer app which I have launched. Whenever I want to check if the Tcl script does what it is supposed to I save it, switch to the waveform viewer and click "reload" on the corresponding Tcl function. If I am unlucky, I will get `file not found` error.
3. I have a tool (Perl script) which does a couple of things, and in the end saves some output to a text file. Immediately after the text file is written to, it submits the edited file to a revision control system. Sometimes, I will get `could not read file` or `input/output error` from the revision control system.

The issue is particularly irritating because of 3), since it makes the tool crash.

- Has anyone ever seen a similar issue and knows what may cause it?
- Alternatively, does anyone know how do I start debugging such an issue? In the case of 3), I can make the script immediately save some debug information that I could review, I just need to know what information to save.

Comment: Which version of nfs is used? Which os runs on the server?

Comment: I added more system info to the question.